# How do I match nested braces using regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have an LaTeX document I want to match. And I need a RegEx match that matches the following:

```
\ # the backslash in the beginning
[a-zA-Z]+ #a word
(\{.+\})* # any amount of {something}
```

However, and her is the catch;

In the last line, it 1. needs to be greedy and 2. needs to have a matching number of `{}` inside itself.

Meaning if I have the string `\test{something\somthing{9}}`
it would match the whole. And it needs to be in that order (`{}`). So that it doesn't match the following:

> \LaTeX{} is a document preparation system for the \TeX{}

just

> \LaTeX{}

and

> \TeX{}

Help anyone? Maybe someone have an better idea for matching? Should I not use regular expressions?

Comment: It's not a regular thing you want to match, so regular expressions aren't the best choice. That being said, you *can* do it, as most regular expression engines aren't regular these days, but it's still not a good idea.

Comment: If I had any other choice I would have gone for it. But I don't know about any other thing that I can use. Do you have any bether idea? If not, it seems that I'm stuck width RegEx.

Comment: It's not only an even number of `{` and `}` (which you can do with regex), but you also want to make sure that `}}{{` is rejected (there's an equals amount of `{` and `}`!), and you'd want to discard `{` and `}` when they occur in comment-lines. In short: regex is not suited for this.

Comment: Even though the new Ruby 1.9 regex engine supports finding properly nested parentheses, I'm not sure it is exactly what I'd recommend doing. But if you want, search for `\g`, which lets you select a named 'subexpression' or something like that.

Comment: So what is then suited for this?

Comment: Recommend you improve your question title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with recursion:

```
$input = "\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system for the \TeX{}
\latex{something\somthing{9}}";

preg_match_all('~(?<token>
        \\\\ # the slash in the beginning
        [a-zA-Z]+ #a word
        (\{[^{}]*((?P>token)[^{}]*)?\}) # {something}
)~x', $input, $matches);
```

This correctly matches `\LaTeX{}`, `\TeX{}`, and `\latex{something\somthing{9}}`

Answer (score 2):

PHP *could* be used since it supports recursive regex-matching. **But**, as I said, if you have comments in your LaTeX-like strings that can have `{` or `}` in them, this will fail.

A demo:

```
$text = 'This is a \LaTeX{ foo { bar { ... } baz test {} done } } document
preparation system for the \TeX{a{b{c}d}e{f}g{h}i}-y people out there';
preg_match_all('/\\\\[A-Za-z]+(\{(?:[^{}]|(?1))*})/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

which produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => \LaTeX{ foo { bar { ... } baz test {} done } }
            [1] => { foo { bar { ... } baz test {} done } }
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => \TeX{a{b{c}d}e{f}g{h}i}
            [1] => {a{b{c}d}e{f}g{h}i}
        )

)
```

A quick explanation:

```
\\\\         # the literal '\'
[A-Za-z]+    # one or more letters
(            # start capture group 1   <-----------------+
  \{         #   the literal '{'                         |
  (?:        #   start non-capture group A               |
    [^{}]    #     any character other than '{' and '}'  |
    |        #     OR                                    |
    (?1)     #     recursively match capture group 1  ---+
  )          #   end non-capture group A
  *          #   non-capture group A zero or more times
  }          #   the literal '}'
)            # end capture group 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I believe this is impossible. Bracket matching (detecting properly paired, nested brackets) is commonly used as an example of a problem that cannot be solved with a finite state machine, such as a regular expression parser. You could do it with a context free grammar, but that's just not how regex works. Your best solution is to use a regex like `{*[^{}]*}*` for the initial check, and then another short script to check whether it's an even number.

In conclusion: don't try and do it with only regex. This is not a problem that can be solved with regex alone.